# Can I search two extension at same time, the code is giving me type mismatch error, while searching for extension .csv and .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel, csv

For extension (`LExtension`) it is given me error message : "Type Mismatch"
I have extension files like `.xlsx` and `.csv`, however it is given an error message.
The code is not taking both the extensions in single line. If I used and,Or it is giving me an error message.
`LExtension = ""` (Is consider blank)

```
Sub CheckIfFileExists()
    Dim LRow As Integer
    Dim LPath As String
    Dim LExtension As String
    Dim LContinue As Boolean

    LContinue = True
    LRow = 3
    LPath = "D:\Raw Files\"
    LExtension = ".CSV" And ".xlsx"    '<--- Type Mismatch error in this line


    While LContinue

        If Len(Range("M" & CStr(LRow)).Value) = 0 Then
            LContinue = False

        Else
            If Len(Dir(LPath & Range("M" & CStr(LRow)).Value & LExtension)) = 0 Then
                Range("N" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "No"
            Else
                Range("N" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "Yes"
            End If
        End If

        LRow = LRow + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

Please help on this.
Your help will be grateful.

Comment: `LExtension = ".CSV" And ".xlsx"` is throwing the error because you're using `And` as a ***bitwise*** operator on that line, and you can't bit-bash two strings together.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileSystemObject` to look for the file. Add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your workbook. then add the following declaration in your Sub:

```
Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
```

Now change your `If Len(Dir(...` to

```
If oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".csv") OR _
   oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".slsx") Then
```

Better practice would be to not use just `Cells`. I would use the reference to the worksheet you are working with (i.e. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells`). Also make sure to clear the object from the memory before you exit the sub (i.e. `Set oFSO = Nothing`) .. again, good practice 
**NOTE**: you don't need to change `LRow` to a string when referencing a `Cell` or `Range`

Comment: @Nilesh If this helped, please don't forget to accept the answer as that is how points are achieved in stackoverflow

Comment: Hi Zac,Thanks for your help. While i put 'Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject', it is giving me an error message "Compile Error".

Comment: Did you add the reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`? If you haven't, from your menu, select: `Tools>References..`. This displays the `References` window. Scroll down until you see `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and select it.

Comment: Run the code till " Else
            If oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".csv") Or _
   oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".xlsx"), then" getting an error message 'Object Variable or With block variable not set'.

Comment: Sub CheckIfFileExists()

   Dim LRow As Integer
   Dim LPath As String
   Dim LExtension As String
   Dim LContinue As Boolean
   Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject

Comment: LContinue = True
   LRow = 3
   LPath = "D:\Raw Files\"
   
   While LContinue

         If Len(Range("M" & CStr(LRow)).Value) = 0 Then
            LContinue = False


      Else
            If oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".csv") Or _
   oFSO.FileExists(LPath & Cells(LRow, "M").Value & ".xlsx") Then
            Range("N" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "No"
      Else
            Range("N" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "Yes"
         End If
      End If

      LRow = LRow + 1

   Wend

Set oFSO = Nothing


End Sub

Comment: Wend

Set oFSO = Nothing


End Sub

Comment: Before your `LContinue = True` line, add the following `Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject`. This will set your `filesystemobject`